# View facade in WPF with ItemsControl or ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, facade

i want create a new WPF application, for the UI i bought a third party component. But i don't want to use them directly, i want a facade between my xaml code and the component.

To build a facade in WPF, you can build your own controls, inherit (from ItemsControl, if control should have multiple children, otherwise from ContentControl) and use your own Controls in xaml. Later on rendering you create the third party component controls.

Concrete: the third party components have a LayoutComponent, a GroupComponent and EditorComponents. So in my facade i want to build a CustomLayoutControl, a CustomGroupControl and all my CustomEditorControls, and all of them should create a corresponding third party ComponentControl. The best would be, if my custom controls don't even exists in the LogicalChildTree.

I read many posts about wpf that sais, WPF works completely different, don't try to use your old knowledge like inheriting controls like it was in WinForms, use modern WPF techniques like templates.

I tried to build a control template for my CustomLayoutControl, but i wasn't able to build this in code. And building a base xaml file is also not possible because you cannot inherit from a xamlfile.

My CustomLayoutControl:

```
internal class CustomLayoutControl : ItemsControl
{
    private readonly LayoutComponent _layoutControl;

    public CustomLayoutControl()
    {
        _layoutControl = new LayoutComponent();
        _layoutControl.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        var result = item is CustomGroupControl;
        return false; // result is true, but with return true i don't come in GetContainerForItemOverride - and so i don't get my LayoutComponent in the Xaml Tree;
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return _layoutControl;
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

        if (element is LayoutComponent && item is CustomGroupControl group)
        {
            // Later check columns and other stuff here and build Components like i need it...

            _layoutControl.Children.Add(group); // EXCEPTION - Object already belongs to a parent object

            // i also tried this, but no GroupComponent is shown in the Visual Studio Xaml Live Visual Tree
            // _layoutControl.Children.Add(group.LayoutGroup);
        }
    }

    public int Columns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Columns.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(int), typeof(CustomLayoutControl), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( -1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
}
```

My CustomGroupControl:

```
internal class CustomGroupControl : ItemsControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<CustomEditorControlBase> _controls;

    public CustomGroupControl()
    {
        _controls = new ObservableCollection<CustomEditorControlBase>();

        LayoutGroup = new GroupComponent();
        LayoutGroup.ItemSpace = 10;
        LayoutGroup.Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 0);
        LayoutGroup.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
        LayoutGroup.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return false;
        return item is CustomEditorControlBase;
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return LayoutGroup;
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

        // I dont hit a breakpoint here
    }

    public GroupComponent LayoutGroup { get; }

    public string Caption { get; set; }

    //#region Columns Property
    /// <summary>
    /// Setzt die Anzahl der Spalten,die in der OWPage vorgehalten werden soll, oder legt dies fest.
    /// </summary>
    public int Columns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Columns.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(int), typeof(CustomGroupControl), new PropertyMetadata(-1, null));
}
```

in xaml i want to use something like this:

```xml
<CustomLayoutControl Columns="2">
    <CustomGroupControl Caption="Others" Columns="3">
        <CustomTextEitor Label="FirstName" />
        <CustomTextEitor/>
    </CustomGroupControl>

    <CustomGroupControl Caption="Dates" Columns="1">
        <CustomDateEitor/>
        <CustomDateEitor/>
    </CustomGroupControl>
</CustomLayoutControl>
```

On render the xaml code should be replaced with this:

```xml
<CompSrc:LayoutComponent>
    <CompSrc:GroupComponent HeaderText="Others">
        <CompSrc:LayoutItemComponent Caption="FirstName">
            <CompSrc:TextComponent/>
        </CompSrc:LayoutItemComponent>
        <CompSrc:LayoutItemComponent>
            <CompSrc:TextComponent/>
        </CompSrc:LayoutItemComponent>
    </CompSrc:GroupComponent>
    <CompSrc:GroupComponent Caption="Dates">
        <CompSrc:LayoutItemComponent>
            <CompSrc:DateComponent/>
        </CompSrc:LayoutItemComponent>
        <CompSrc:LayoutItemComponent>
            <CompSrc:DateComponent/>
        </CompSrc:LayoutItemComponent>
    </CompSrc:GroupComponent>
</CompSrc:LayoutComponent>
```

So my question is, how can i inherit from ItemsControl to get this work? I don't know what i'm missing. First problem, that all my CustomControls exist in the LogicalTreeView (maybe thats not a problem, but i think the less controls in the tree, the less performance it cost).
Next problem is the exception in CustomLayoutControl.PrepareContainerForItemOverride, that sais that my CustomGroupControl already belongs to a parent object. So i don't come out in the CustomGroupControl.PrepareContainerForItemOverride

Comment: `return _layoutControl;` and `return LayoutGroup;` in GetContainerForItemOverride() looks odd. You can't use a single container object for multiple items.

Comment: ok, sounds interesting Clemens, but if i use my third party components directly, i only have one CompSrc:LayoutComponent for all my GroupComponents. How should this work?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I do not at all understand what all this is supposed to be. Why won't you just use those third-party controls in DataTemplates?

Comment: I build a whole framework and i need a strict separation. I dont want that these components are referenced in my app directly. So i have the ability to switch them later, if needed. Next is, that many developers will work with that facade. if i dont have it, every developer will build UI in his own style, so every view looks a little bit different (3 developers would build the same ui in 3 different ways).